# Set calendar options with Selenium (on Python)

Tags: python, date, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to set calendar dates to access some data on a website:
`https://www.investing.com/rates-bonds/japan-10-year-bond-yield-historical-data`
Unfortunately, the elements of the calendar do not appear in the HTML of the page on my browser.

I have tried using the send_keys function of the selenium driver. Dates are never what I input in the first place. When I try to change the input of the calendar section as shown below, the dates respond incorrectly:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*/div[@class=\"DatePickerWrapper_icon-wrap__AVK7m\"]').click()

d = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')

d.send_keys('01-02-2020')
```

Does anyone know how to set the dates properly? Thanks!